# Parse Years in Python 3.4 Pandas and Bokeh from counter dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I'm struggling with creating a Bokeh time series graph from the output of the `counter` function from `collections`.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import collections

plotyears = []
counter = collections.Counter(plotyears)
output_file("years.html")
p = figure(width=800, height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")

for number in sorted(counter):
    yearvalue = number, counter[number]
    p.line(yearvalue, color='navy', alpha=0.5)
show(p)
```

The output of `yearvalue` when printed is:

```
(2013, 132)
(2014, 188)
(2015, 233)
```

How can I make bokeh make the years as x-axis and numbers as y-axis. I have tried to follow the [Time series tutorial](http://%3Chttp://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.9.3/docs/user_guide/charts.html#timeseries), but I can't use the `pd.read_csv` and p`arse_dates=['Date']` functionalities since I'm not reading a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is to convert your data into a pandas DataFrame (with pd.DataFrame) and after create a datetime column with your year column.

simple example :

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
output_notebook()

years = [2012,2013,2014,2015]
val   = [230,120,200,340]

# Convert your data into a panda DataFrame format 
data=pd.DataFrame({'year':years, 'value':val})

# Create a new column (yearDate) equal to the year Column but with a datetime format
data['yearDate']=pd.to_datetime(data['year'],format='%Y')

# Create a line graph with datetime x axis and use datetime column(yearDate) for this axis 
p = figure(width=800, height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.line(x=data['yearDate'],y=data['value'])
show(p)
```

Comment: Great! That totally worked. Thanks a lot! I made a little change to make bokeh print a file instead. Like this:

    `import pandas as pd
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
    import collections`

Then adding:

    `output_file("years.html")`